# Why code create wrong Binary search tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to create a Binary search tree sicne morning and i am still not able to do,
  I get wrong output when i see the tree formed on debugging then it is not correct.

How i do ?

```
(1) I have an array of values which will be data of each node in tree.
(2) I create the root node and pass that node in CreateBinarySearchTree(&RootOfTree, values, size); function.
(3) In  CreateBinarySearchTree(Tree**RootOfTree, int* values, int size) definition  i have 4 conditions:

if ((*RootOfTree)->left == NULL && (*RootOfTree)->right == NULL){...}
else if ((*RootOfTree)->left == NULL && (*RootOfTree)->right != NULL){..}
else if ((*RootOfTree)->left != NULL && (*RootOfTree)->right == NULL){..}
and else{ CreateBinarySearchTree(&(*RootOfTree)->left, values, size);}
```

My full code is here :

```
       // BinaryTree.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

struct Tree
{
    Tree*left = NULL;
    Tree*right = NULL;
    int data;

};
int counte = 0;
int values[] = { 8, 5, 4, 9, 7, 11, 1, 12, 3, 2 };
int val = values[counte];
Tree*storeRoot = NULL;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Tree *tree = NULL;
    void CreateBinarySearchTree(Tree**RootOfTree, int* values, int size);

    int size = sizeof(values) / sizeof(values[1]);
    Tree* RootOfTree = NULL;
    if (tree == NULL)
    {
        tree = new Tree();
        RootOfTree = tree;
        tree->data = values[0];
        tree->left = NULL;
        tree->right = NULL;
    }
    storeRoot = RootOfTree;
    CreateBinarySearchTree(&RootOfTree, values, size);
    return 0;
}

void CreateBinarySearchTree(Tree**RootOfTree, int* values, int size)
{

    Tree *tree = NULL;
    if (counte > size)
    {
        return;
    }

    if ((*RootOfTree)->left == NULL && (*RootOfTree)->right == NULL)
    {
        counte++;
        val = values[counte];
        tree = new Tree();
        tree->data = val;
        tree->left = NULL;
        tree->right = NULL;
        if ((*RootOfTree)->data < val)
        {
            (*RootOfTree)->right = tree;
        }
        else if ((*RootOfTree)->data > val)
        {
            (*RootOfTree)->left = tree;
        }
        CreateBinarySearchTree(&(*RootOfTree), values, size);
    }
    else if ((*RootOfTree)->left == NULL && (*RootOfTree)->right != NULL)
    {
        counte++;
        val = values[counte];
        if ((*RootOfTree)->data > val)
        {
            tree = new Tree();
            tree->data = val;
            tree->left = NULL;
            tree->right = NULL;
            (*RootOfTree)->left = tree;
        }
        else
        {
            counte--;
            CreateBinarySearchTree(&(*RootOfTree)->right, values, size);
        }
    }
    else if ((*RootOfTree)->left != NULL && (*RootOfTree)->right == NULL)
    {
        counte++;
        val = values[counte];
        if ((*RootOfTree)->data < val)
        {
            if (storeRoot->data > val)
            {
                tree = new Tree();
                tree->data = val;
                tree->left = NULL;
                tree->right = NULL;
                (*RootOfTree)->right = tree;
            }
            else
            {
                if (storeRoot->right == NULL)
                {
                    tree = new Tree();
                    tree->data = val;
                    tree->left = NULL;
                    tree->right = NULL;
                    (storeRoot)->right = tree;
                }
                else
                {
                    counte--;
                    CreateBinarySearchTree(&storeRoot, values, size);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            counte--;
            CreateBinarySearchTree(&(*RootOfTree)->left, values, size);
        }
    }
}
```

Please correct me wherever i am wrong so that it will create binary searach tree. **Please also give detail explanation while answering, Thanks**

Comment: But it is compiling..where you think is the problem ? please see this http://prntscr.com/9jwogy

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot declare a function inside of another function like you've done in your main function.

Comment: I've removed the comment.

Comment: Your first course of action should be to get rid of the global variables. Globals are extra super-bad in combination with recursion. (Why is `RootOfTree` a `Tree**`when you never assign to `*RootOfTree`?)

Comment: Can you give us some idea of what the problem is? How is the created tree not correct? Have you single-stepped your code in the debugger to see what it's doing? Have you tested creating a simple tree with just two or three nodes, and see if that works? You've posted 100+ lines of code and said, basically, "fix this for me." That's not what we do here. You have to put forth a little more effort than that.

Comment: I was following your code until it started using `storeRoot`.  Then I decided it just isn't worth the grief, and so should you!  Thinking like a programmer means generalizing, **NOT** splitting into an excessive set of sub cases.  You don't need separate code for the first item nor for almost every other case you broke out.  You have a `Tree**`.  If that points to NULL then that is where the next node goes.  If that points to a non NULL, you recurse into one side or the other with one value comparison. 2 `if` statements, 3 cases, done!

Comment: Ok, could some one please write me function Definiton of void CreateBinarySearchTree(Tree**RootOfTree, int* values, int size) {code inside}  by your own perfect way of doing so that i can read it and understand it and will use it as reference for future. ??

Comment: @JimMischel Yes i have tried what you all suggested. It creates a tree but miss many nodes in that tree, i feel like my algorithm is wrong. Could you please write it once ,if you have to do it , then how you would have written the code in  function definitionCreateBinarySearchTree(Tree*RootOfTree, int values, int size) {} ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from the top. What is a binary search tree (BST)? A binary search tree is a data structure where each node to the left of a given node contains a value *smaller* than it and each node to the right of a given node contains a value *greater* than it. The binary search tree also has a single root node.

Take a look at your code. You're thinking that the root of a tree *is a tree itself* (root of tree is a `Tree` type). This is incorrect; the root of a tree is a node. Each node stores a value, and two pointers to other nodes: its left and right children. Let's translate that into code:

```
class BST {

public:
    BST() : head(nullptr) {}
    ~BST() { /* Implement */ }
    void insert(int value);
private:
    struct Node{
        Node(int d, Node *l = nullptr, Node *r = nullptr) : data(d), left(l), right(r) {} 
        int data;
        Node *left, *right;
    } *head;
    void insert(Node *n, int val);
};
```

Now, onto your insertion algorithm. Your creation function should handle all the details of creating the tree. That is, your user really shouldn't be responsible for creating the tree and passing it in. That would be contradictory to the name of your function. Moreover, your function creates too many subcases that could easily be generalized. We want to check for three things:

1. Is the tree empty (e.g. is the root pointing to nullptr)?
2. If it is, populate the root and return.
3. Otherwise, check the insertion value and recurse down the tree until you get to a suitable location for the value.

You can easily implement this using our new OOP design and delegate the actual insertion to a private member function. The reason we do that is because we only want to modify the head pointer when we're changing what it points to (either when the tree is empty and we're populating it or when we're destroying the tree). In all other cases, we want the head pointer to simply be a starting point for our insertion function. Delegating our insertion to a private insertion function taking the head as a pointer will *copy the head pointer* and therefore not modify the original one:

```
void BST::insert(int value) 
{
    insert(head, value);
}

void BST::insert(Node *n, int val)
{
    if (!head) {
        head = new Node(val);
        return;
    }

    if (val < n->data) {
        if (n->left)
            insert(n->left, val);
        else
            n->left = new Node(val);
    } else if (val > n->data) {
        if (n->right)
            insert(n->right, val);
        else
            n->right = new Node(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a significant cleanup compared to the version in the question, but still seriously special cased and heavy compared to a good design:  If the second function had signature `static void insert(Node**n, int val)` and was called with `insert(&head,value)` it can all be simpler, more efficient and more easily extended to more interesting types of tree.

Comment: Also a programming student should be aware, there is no reason for the function to be recursive, and if it were not recursive there would be no reason for a separate wrapper function to launch the recursion.  In more interesting trees that is often needed.  But not in this trivial tree.  Any decent optimizer will inline your recursive `insert` as a non recursive loop in the top level `insert` function.  You don't need to do that.  But a programming student ought to know how and usually should not write gratuitous recursion for the optimizer to remove.